# Two set of Int32 - fastest way to count the intersection

Tags: .net, hashset

I have almost 1 million items and each item has a unique set of Int32 I will call idS

For each pair of item (1 million x (1 million -1))
I need a count of idS that match

Here is what I am doing now

```
foreach (Item item1 in Items) 
{
    HashSet<Int32> idS1 = item1.idS;
    foreach(Item item2 in Items.Where(x => x.ID > item1.ID)
    {
       HashSet<Int32> idS2 = item2.idS;
       Int32 matchCount = 0;
       if (idS1.Count < idS2.Count)
       {
           foreach(Int32 i1 in idS1) 
               if(idS2.Contains(i1)) matchCount++;
       }
       else 
       {
           foreach(Int32 i2 in idS2) 
               if(idS1.Contains(i2)) matchCount++;
       }
    }
}
```

Is there a faster way?
I tried IntersectWith and is is slower.
I don't need the actual intersection - just the count.

Not interested in parallel as will run with a production load so want to limit it to a single CPU

Regarding a sorted set there is more
I am not interested in low intersection
If the large count is > 4 * the low count I don't skip
When I read in from SQL I sort by count
And I delete the low counts (what I have it 3 rolling sets where set 2 is twice counts and set 3 is 4 x the count)
I needed rolling set just to stay under OOM

This is everything

```
public void Logon()
{
        sqlCon1 = new SqlConnection(connString);
        sqlCon2 = new SqlConnection(connString);
        sqlCon3 = new SqlConnection(connString);
        try
        {
            sqlCon1.Open();
            sqlCon2.Open();
            sqlCon3.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = sqlCon1.CreateCommand();
    SqlCommand sqlcmd2 = sqlCon1.CreateCommand();
    SqlCommand sqlcmd3 = sqlCon1.CreateCommand();
    sqlcmd1.CommandText = "SELECT [FTSindexWordOnce].[sID], [FTSindexWordOnce].[wordID], [docSVsys].[textUniqueWordCount]" + Environment.NewLine +
                          "  FROM [FTSindexWordOnce] with (nolock)" + Environment.NewLine +
                          "  JOIN [docSVsys] with (nolock)" + Environment.NewLine +
                          "    ON [docSVsys].[sID] = [FTSindexWordOnce].[sID] " + Environment.NewLine +
                          " WHERE [docSVsys].[textUniqueWordCount] > 10" + Environment.NewLine +
                          " ORDER BY [docSVsys].[textUniqueWordCount] asc, [FTSindexWordOnce].[sID], [FTSindexWordOnce].[wordID]";
    List<DocUniqueWords> docsA = new List<DocUniqueWords>();
    List<DocUniqueWords> docsB = new List<DocUniqueWords>();
    List<DocUniqueWords> docsC = new List<DocUniqueWords>();
    List<DocUniqueWords> docsActive = docsA;
    List<DocUniqueWords> docs0 = new List<DocUniqueWords>();
    List<DocUniqueWords> docs1 = new List<DocUniqueWords>();
    DocUniqueWords doc = new DocUniqueWords(0);
    Int32 sID;
    Int32 textUniqueWordCount;
    Int32 maxTextUniqueWordCount = 20;
    Int32 ccount = 0;
    byte  textUniqueWordIter = 0;
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader rdr = sqlcmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            textUniqueWordCount = rdr.GetInt32(2);
            if (textUniqueWordCount > maxTextUniqueWordCount)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(maxTextUniqueWordCount.ToString() + " " + ccount.ToString()
                                                   + " " + docsA.Count.ToString() + " " + docsB.Count.ToString() + " " + docsC.Count.ToString());
                maxTextUniqueWordCount = maxTextUniqueWordCount * 2;
                ccount = 0;

                sw.Restart();
                ScoreTwo(docs0, docsActive);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  ScoreTwo(docs0, docsActive)       ElapsedMilliseconds = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0") + " ElapsedMinutes = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 60000m).ToString("N2") + " ElapsedHours = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 3600000m).ToString("N2"));
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ElapsedMilliseconds = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"));
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
                sw.Restart();

                ScoreTwo(docs1, docsActive);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  ScoreTwo(docs1, docsActive)       ElapsedMilliseconds = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0") + " ElapsedMinutes = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 60000m).ToString("N2") + " ElapsedHours = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 3600000m).ToString("N2"));
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ElapsedMilliseconds = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"));
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
                sw.Restart();

                ScoreTwo(docsActive, docsActive);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  ScoreTwo(docsActive, docsActive)  ElapsedMilliseconds = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0") + " ElapsedMinutes = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 60000m).ToString("N2") + " ElapsedHours = " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 3600000m).ToString("N2"));
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ElapsedMilliseconds = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"));
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("");
                sw.Restart();

                switch (textUniqueWordIter)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Console.WriteLine("Case 0");
                        textUniqueWordIter = 1;
                        //docsB.Clear();
                        docs0 = docsC;
                        docs1 = docsA;
                        docsActive = docsB;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
                        textUniqueWordIter = 2;
                        //docsC.Clear();
                        docs0 = docsA;
                        docs1 = docsB;
                        docsActive = docsC;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                        textUniqueWordIter = 0;
                        //docsA.Clear();
                        docs0 = docsA;
                        docs1 = docsC;
                        docsActive = docsC;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                        break;
                }
                docsActive.Clear();
            }
            sID = rdr.GetInt32(0);
            if (doc.SID != sID)
            {
                if (doc.SID != 0 && doc.Words.Count > 0 && ccount < 100000) docsActive.Add(doc);
                doc = new DocUniqueWords(sID);
                ccount++;
            }
            doc.Words.Add(rdr.GetInt32(1));
        }
        rdr.Close();
        if (doc.Words.Count > 0) docsActive.Add(doc);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("docs.Count = " + docsActive.Count.ToString("N0"));

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("done");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
public void ScoreTwo(List<DocUniqueWords> docsOuter, List<DocUniqueWords> docsInner)
{   // docsInner is >= wordcount
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    foreach (DocUniqueWords d1 in docsOuter)
    {
        //if (d1.SID % 1000 == 0) 
        //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("  d1.SID = " + d1.SID.ToString() + "  ElapsedMilliseconds = " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"));
        if (docsOuter == docsInner)
        {
            foreach (DocUniqueWords d2 in docsInner.Where(x => x.SID < d1.SID))
            {
                Int32 hashMatchCount = 0;
                if(d1.Words.Count<= d2.Words.Count)
                {                          
                    foreach (Int32 d1sID in d1.Words)
                        if (d2.Words.Contains(d1sID)) hashMatchCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Int32 d2sID in d2.Words)
                        if (d1.Words.Contains(d2sID)) hashMatchCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DocUniqueWords d2 in docsInner)
            {
                if (d1.Words.Count * 4 >= d2.Words.Count)
                {
                    Int32 hashMatchCount = 0;
                    foreach (Int32 d1sID in d1.Words)
                        if (d2.Words.Contains(d1sID)) hashMatchCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Int32 kkk = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try LINQ's Count?

Comment: Perhaps some background information could help. For example what do those sets actually look like? Could they be dense bit arrays?

Comment: Can you try to insert the second set into the first without allowing duplicates and count the failures?  That would get it closer to O(n), no?

Comment: The set of Int32 is fairly random with valued from 1 - 20,000.  Each item have from 1 to 10,000 values and most are 40 - 400 unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the answer you would expect
I could not beat a cursor

```
select 'starting'
set nocount on
--
 IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#UniqueWords', N'U') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #UniqueWords 
 CREATE TABLE #UniqueWords (wordID INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED); 
 --
 IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#docMatchScore', N'U') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #docMatchScore 
 CREATE TABLE #docMatchScore (sID1 INT, sID2 INT, matchCount INT, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (sID1, sID2)); 
 --
 declare @sID int;

 declare @wordCountBase int;
 declare @wordCountComp int;


DECLARE score_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT [sID], count(*)
   from [FTSindexWordOnce] with (nolock)
--WHERE [sID] < 10000
  GROUP BY [sID]
  ORDER BY [sID];
OPEN score_cursor
Select 'FETCH NEXT FROM predict_cursor'
FETCH NEXT FROM score_cursor 
INTO @sID, @wordCountBase
Select 'starting cursor'

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    truncate table #UniqueWords;
    insert into #UniqueWords ([wordID])
    select [wordID] 
      from [FTSindexWordOnce] with (nolock)
     where [sID] = @sid 
     order by [wordID];

    --insert into #docMatchScore (sID1, sID2, matchCount)
    insert into [ftsIndexWordMatch] with (tablock) (sID1, sID2, matchCount) 
    select @sID, [FTSindexWordOnce].[sID], count(#UniqueWords.[wordID]) 
      from [FTSindexWordOnce] with (nolock)
      join [docSVsys] with (nolock) 
        on [FTSindexWordOnce].[sID] > @sID
       and [docSVsys].[sID] = [FTSindexWordOnce].[sID]
       and [docSVsys].[textUniqueWordCount] * 4 >= @wordCountBase 
       and [docSVsys].[textUniqueWordCount]     <= @wordCountBase * 4
      left join #UniqueWords 
        on #UniqueWords.[wordID] = [FTSindexWordOnce].[wordID]
      left join [ftsIndexWordMatch] 
        on [ftsIndexWordMatch].[sID1] = @sID
       and [ftsIndexWordMatch].[sID2] = [FTSindexWordOnce].[sID]
     where [ftsIndexWordMatch].[sID1] is null
       and [ftsIndexWordMatch].[sID2] is null
     --and [FTSindexWordOnce].[sID] < 1000
     group by [FTSindexWordOnce].[sID]

    FETCH NEXT FROM score_cursor 
    INTO @sID, @wordCountBase
END 
CLOSE score_cursor;
DEALLOCATE score_cursor;
-- 
select * from #docMatchScore
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#UniqueWords', N'U') IS NOT NULL     DROP TABLE #UniqueWords
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#docMatchScore', N'U') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #docMatchScore
Select 'done'
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be because the arrays are sorted in that case? Because then you can advance your index on both side "simultaneously" to find the matches.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be under the impression that the intersection is slow, but it's not.

**For million items, it will be few milliseconds probably.**

I can't say the same for your outer loop, this will be quite slow:

```
foreach (Item item1 in Items) 
{
    HashSet<Int32> idS1 = item1.idS;
    foreach(Item item2 in Items.Where(x => x.ID > item1.ID)
    ...
```

By the sounds of it, O(n^2) if I am right. The trick here is to presort your Item list, so you wouldn't need the `Where` condition.

Comment: Yes compare n items with n items is O(n^2).  But that is what I need to do. How would you make that faster?

Comment: Getting a quadratic number of outputs is always going to take at least quadratic time

Comment: @BLam: Ill try to add some code later, but you can sort it before.

Comment: @harold: You're right, though, It's unclear what the OP wants to do with the `matchCount`. It might be possible to get rid of the "quadratic number of outputs" requirement.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa there is more that kind of prevent that.  Will update the question.

Comment: I added the full code.  Yes I think I could make List<DocUniqueWords> a sortedset.

Comment: I added a sorted set but it made almost no difference.  The where does not take very long and it eliminates 1/2 rows.  It is way faster then processing twice as many rows.

Comment: The intersection is not slow relative to the hashcount.  The hashcount takes 200 time as long as the foreach loops.  The hashcount has a foreach.

Comment: @Blam: I don't understand what is going on in your code, or what you're trying to do. You're doing **nothing** with hashMatchCount.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Correct I am not doing anything with hashMatchCount in the posted code.  I omitted that code as it is not a problem.  The question is how to do that calculation as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do set intersections between two lists with 100,000,000 elements each in often just a few iterations and in under a millisecond. However, it's not an easy data structure to implement and you have to store the indices directly into this structure. This should give you an idea though:

[image]

A reasonably good way to do it that's not nearly as fast (linear time complexity always) if the values of the integers don't have an astronomical range is to just use a parallel array of bits, like so:

[image]

Just iterate through the first list of indices and mark the bits, then iterate through the second list and look for bits that are marked. There's your set intersection in linear time with a much, much, cheaper `m` than a hash table. If you just need a count, just increment a counter instead of inserting the result to a list.